# facebook login issue - canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

When I click on login with Facebook button, it is opening safari browser and getting closed immediately. Noticed error on the console.

App delegate method:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print("###### URL : ")
    print(url)
    print("###### App : ")
    print(app)
    print(options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"])
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, openURL: url,  sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String,
            annotation: nil)
}
```

```
2015-09-18 18:37:51.410 [21036:5050465] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"

2015-09-18 18:37:51.417[21036:5050465] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"

###### URL : 

fb4554284912963222://authorize/?error_code=100&error_message=Invalid+Scope%3A+public&state=%7B%22challenge%22%3A%222ZmK6R5F05d%252F060TkCqj8SjPLjc%253D%22%2C%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%223C79F2C8-61B9-470E-AE1B-E1C68435DB83%22%2C%22com.facebook.sdk_client_state%22%3Atrue%2C%223_method%22%3A%22sfvc_auth%22%7D&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A145973.000512302%7D#_=_

###### App : 


Optional(com.apple.SafariViewService)
nil

###### err:

Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid Scope: public, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0})
```

IDE : xcode 7
Language : Swift2
Facebook SDK : 4.6.0
Parse: 1.8.4

I have also verified .plist is having all keys which are required.
Also verified the bundle identifier for typo mistakes. All look good.
Facebook is active.

Any help?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm in the same boat, have all they keys defined and my users cannot login to Facebook unless it is the native iOS dialog. Web view and app switch both fail.

Comment: Any luck here? My Share Dialog is messing up :(

Comment: Can you share your code on the git and i will check it.

Comment: I was stuck on the same issue and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32960621/5405653) saved me

Answer (score 45):

I have the same warning, but in Facebook Docs there is an answer.

> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Answer (score 38):

The "-canOpenURL: failed for URL" warning is a red herring and simply means the FB app is not installed on the device/simulator you're running on.

It looks like you're requesting an invalid scope (aka permission) of "Public". Can you include your code that includes what permissions you are asking? public_profile is probably what you want (and what the SDK defaults to if none are provided).

More importantly, do **NOT** add fbauth2 to your CFBundleURLSchemes as that will break login flows. As Himanshu pointed out, those entries should be entered under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in our plist.

Comment: My god the documentation for this is an absolute disaster. And I thought I couldn't like Facebook any less.

Answer (score 4):

If you're recompiling with iOS SDK 9.0, add the following to your application's plist if you're using a version of the Facebook SDK v4.6.0 or above:

```
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
          <string>fbapi</string>
          <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
          <string>fbauth2</string>
          <string>fbshareextension</string>
   </array>
```

To prepare the facebook integration supported to iOS 9, go through [Facebook Integraion for iOS 9 guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

To check version of facebook SDK, use below line of code:

```
   print("SDK version \(FBSDKSettings .sdkVersion())")
```

Answer (score 3):

> This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned
>   false. As long as you have configured the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`
>   entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning.

Go to this [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=ios) Select Your App, And configure your `info.plist`

`import` And add this code in your `AppDelegate`

```
import FBSDKCoreKit .  
import FBSDKLoginKit

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have missed the importing `FBSDKCoreKit`. Later it started working on the simulator but not on the iPhone device.

Also noticed the following FAQ on the Facebook site. Why do I see console messages like

> 'canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb...://'

or ? This is a Xcode warning indicating the `canOpenURL:` call returned false. As long as you have configured the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entry in your `plist` as described above, you can ignore this warning

Regarding not working on the iPhone device, please refer: 
[Parse API - Facebook login not working on the iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670555/parse-api-facebook-login-not-working-on-the-iphone-device/32670628)

Comment: I can ignore the warning but Facebook's view controller does not show up.

Comment: Did you import all required packages?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this method if your app is running on iOS9 or above.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                  openURL:url
                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
```

}

In case you need a Swift version:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app,
                                                     open: url,
                                                     sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] as Any)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. It was just the syntax in loginButtonClicked function. The error message was leading me down the wrong path. Here is the working code.

```
@objc func loginButtonClicked() {
    self.login = FBSDKLoginManager()

    self.login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self, handler: {(result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Process error")
        }
        else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
            print("Cancelled")
        }
        else {
            print("Logged in")
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                let viewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UITabBarController") as! UITabBarController
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }

        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra "/" in your url "fbauth2:///".

Then you can see "error_message=Invalid+Scope" in the url, you should probably check the permissions of your app:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4

Comment: I did not use any URL. Any specific URL you are talking about? I have just used <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
 </array> in .plist file.

Comment: MY bad. I have missed  the importing **FBSDKCoreKit**. Later it started working on the simulator but **not on the iPhone device**. Also noticed the following FAQ on the Facebook site. Why do I see console messages like 'canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb...://' or ?

This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to App Transport Security introduced in iOS 9.

There are two solutions, both deal with fixing your info.plist file

Here's a guide http://discoverpioneer.com/blog/2015/09/18/updating-facebook-integration-for-ios-9/

Comment: This page is not active anymore. Can you post the solution please?