# Facebook Login issue,without termination of app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, authentication

why this error is showing up ?

canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Comment: i hope [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663382/facebook-login-issue-canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-error-null) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please add fbauth2 in url schema of info.plist file of your xcode project.
Also add

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key> <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string> </array>
```

in your info.plist file.
for more information https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9