# iOS Firebase Facebook failed for URL error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have integrated `Firebase` and `Facebook` sdks with my app. I am trying to use `Facebook` login to authenticate with `Firebase`.

Every time I call `FBSDKLoginManager` `logIn` method, I get this error:

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I am using `Firebase (5.15.0)`, `FirebaseAuth (5.2.0)` and `FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.1)`

Comment: Hi, did you checked this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663382/facebook-login-issue-canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-error-null
In the fb docs it says:
Why do I see console messages like "canOpenURL: failed for URL: fb...://"?

This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in your plist as described above, you can ignore this warning

Comment: @BrunoLoops Thanks for referring to this. It is right

Comment: Well I'm kind of new here
So should I mark this as duplicate? or make an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: @BrunoLoops Make and answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is discussed in this question: [facebook login issue - canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663382/facebook-login-issue-canopenurl-failed-for-url-fbauth2-error-null)
In the Facebook documentation says:

> Why do I see console messages like "canOpenURL: failed for URL: fb...://"? This is an Xcode warning indicating the the canOpenURL: call returned false. As long as you have configured the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, you can ignore this warning

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9